# Typo3 Formhandler Default Values not working

Tags: typo3

I got a problem with Typo3 and Default Values. I add them like this:

```
preProcessors {
    1.class = Tx_Formhandler_PreProcessor_LoadDefaultValues
    1.config {
      1 {
        name.defaultValue = TEXT
        name.defaultValue.value = Name
        email.defaultValue = TEXT
        email.defaultValue.data = E-Mail
      }
    }
  }
```

and here is my html template:

```
<input class="input_textfield" type="text" name="formhandlerfooter[name]" id="name" value="###value_name###" />
```

which doesn't seem to work. If I put those values directly into my template-file, the required check won't work. I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you have this config nested properly it should be (when placed on the top level of your TS):

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.preProcessors {
    1.class = Tx_Formhandler_PreProcessor_LoadDefaultValues
    1.config {
        1 {
            name.defaultValue = TEXT
            name.defaultValue.value = Name
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, defaultValue is still a value, so if I understand you right, you want to use HTML's `placeholder` attribute instead  (no need for any TS config)

```
<input placeholder="Your name here" class="input_textfield" type="text" name="formhandlerfooter[name]" id="name" value="###value_name###" />
```